# How to restore data in Android?

Tags: android

I recently got into Android development and I'm a bit confused about how the savedInstanceState works. Let's say I was making a game and I want to save the player's score, would I be able to save it during `onSavedInstanceState()` to the savedInstanceState Bundle and always be able to retrieve the score from it no matter whether the device was shut off or the user just completely closed the app?

Comment: if ur data is small use shared pref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how much is Bundle object kept in mememory, that would be temporarily.

The data is held in memory until the application is alive or killed by the OS (lack of memory), in other words if you force close the app (shut down the device or close the app) onSaveInstanceState is not used.

However if you want to permanently store the data you would have to use SharedPreferences and SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand you but let me answer you and then tell me if this what you mean

the savedInstanceState has nothing to do with the save game, the save game usually should be when a cretin event happens or sometimes you choose that

if the user closed the game by pressing the home button for example you will save the game automatically for him , you should do that by overriding one of the Activity methods, onPause() is your best bet, because you want to keep the save even if the user restarted his phone for example.

see this for activity life cycle:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

On the other hand, the savedInstanceState is a mechanism used by android to save the activity temporarily, if the user went back to the game directly before the activity completely gets killed by the OS, you can restore the state of the activity instead of loading the game from the beginning and going to the start menu.

this principle holds in general not just in game.

to summarize it: the savedInstanceState is a way to restore your activity form the memory before it gets killed rather than loading it again. and it's NOT a way to save data premenantlly on the device

if this is what you want, then you can ask about how to work with the savedInstanceState